# Tailwind CSS: require(...) is not a function error in VSCode

Tags: craft3, error, vscode

Maybe it's something stupid I'm overlooking, but nevertheless I tried everything to overcome this error. I followed the tutorial step by step, so maybe I'm looking totally in the wrong direction here :-D

[image: Tailwind CSS: require(...) is not a function error in VSCode]

And this is the path configured in tailwind.config.js:

[image]

To verify that the path is correct, I made subtle adjustments to it, which gave me some other error:

[image]

Anyone who has an idea where to go / look from here? :-)

Thank you very much in advance for thinking with me!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it not directly related to Craft CMS.

Answer (score 2):

Open the Settings for the Tailwind IntelliSense Extension and add `**/vendor/**` to the **Files: Exclude** section.

[image: Extension settings]